# Why is my totalTokens variable getting the wrong output at the end of my loop?

Tags: c#, function, variables

Why is my totalTokens variable getting the wrong output at the end of my loop?  If I bet the same amount for each guess it gives me the right output, but if the user bets different amounts on each guess it provides the wrong output.

```
int returnValue = random.Next(1, 100);
string input;
int guess = 0;
int count = 0;
int tokens = 1000;
int bet = 0;
int totalTokens;
int betResult = 0;
int countB = 0;
int victory = 50;           

Console.WriteLine("What is your bet?");
bet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 100)
{
    if (guess > returnValue)
    {
        Console.Beep(100,2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too HIGH");
        betResult = - bet;
        countB += 1;
        count += 1;                 
    }
    if (guess < returnValue)
    {                        
        Console.Beep(300,2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Guess Again! Your guess is too LOW");
        betResult = -bet;
        countB += 1;
        count += 1;                     
    }
    if (guess == returnValue)
    {
        totalTokens = tokens + (betResult * countB) + victory;
        Console.Beep(50,2000);
        Console.Beep(60,2000);
        Console.Beep(70,2000);
        Console.WriteLine("You got it RIGHT!!!!!!");
        count += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess of " +returnValue+ " was right.");
        Console.WriteLine("took you " +count+ " guesses to win the game.");
        Console.WriteLine("You won {0} tokens",victory);
        Console.WriteLine("Your total tokens is {0}", totalTokens);
    }                   
}

while (guess != returnValue)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500000);
    Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: What is the scope of `random`?

Comment: Where do you set the value of _guess_? If you don't provide your exact code that reproduces the problem your question is likely to be closed cause lacking of [mcve]

Comment: `totalTokens = tokens + (betResult * countB) + victory;` You're only using the result of the last bet, multiplied by the number of bets. Then obviously, if the amount of each bet is different, this is not gonna work

Comment: the scope is 1-100.... that is defined in separate code i have not copied on here cause im just having a problem with the totalTokens variable at the end

Answer (score 0):

this line actually assigns betResult as last bet:

```
betResult = -bet;
```

you should write:

```
betResult -= bet;
```

Comment: Then the `totalTokens = tokens + (betResult * countB) + victory;` line should be fixed as well